# elasticserarch geo distance filter but distance is on documen instead of in the query

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, geospatial

I have entrys with "xyz" willing to drive a certain distance to a persion.

the range is on the document instead the other way round

how would i be able to structure a query to fullfill this requirement?

thanks

my records look pretty much like this

```html
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "pin": {
"name": "Bradford",
"location": {
  "lat": 51.5,
  "lon": 0.1
}
  },
  "max_travel_radius": "25km"
}
```

the regular geo distance query
would yield wrong results because its not about how far away the "searcher" is from the entry

the entry has a radius  and can be reached by the "searcher"

Comment: Please provide more information on what data format you are getting and how you are getting it and the data format that you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your document having geo_shape instead of a location. Geo_shape that you should use is circle, where you specify person location and max_travel_distance as radius. Please check out circle at this [url](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html). Your input document may look like

```
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "pin": {
      "name": "Bradford",
     "location": {
        "type": circle, 
        "coordinates" : [101.0, 1.0],
        "radius" : "25000m"
      }
  }
}
```

Next you should used [geo_shape query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) to check if a point lies WITHIN in the shape of document you created above. A sample query will be like (You will need to change it for nested query. Just giving an example here)

```
GET /example/_search
{
    "query":{
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "geo_shape": {
                    "location": {
                        "shape": {
                            "type": "point",
                            "coordinates" : [102.0, 2.0]
                        },
                        "relation": "contains"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it was "contains" instaed of "within" but the rest was spot on thank you